# Swift 2.0 Switch between storyboards using iBeacon

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xcode7-beta6

I am working on a project with iBeacon. When the beacon which is closed to my iPhone it changes the background of the stage. Now i got this working i want to turn this to change the storyboards.

```
    self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors[closestBeacon.minor.integerValue]

let colors = [ 
41206: UIColor(red: 84/255, green: 77/255, blue: 160/255, alpha: 1), // uyfu
45528: UIColor(red: 142/255, green: 212/255, blue: 220/255, alpha: 1), // IDOL
46768: UIColor(red: 162/255, green: 213/255, blue: 181/255, alpha: 1), //YBgy
]
```

Are the controllers to change the background.

**My question to all of this is it possible to do it in the same way as the background is changed or do i have to change the code for switching the stages.**